# Is there a largest minimal non-guillotine pattern?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, discrete-geometry, rectangles

In this question, a *pattern* is an finite arrangement of pairwise-disjoint axes-parallel rectangles contained in some larger rectangle.
A *guillotine pattern* (GP) is a pattern in which the rectangles can be separated by a sequence of *guillotine cuts*, which are axes-parallel cuts going from one edge of an available piece to the opposite edge. The interest in guillotine cuts comes from the process of cutting sheets of material in the industry; see [guillotine cutting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillotine_cutting) for more details.

The following arrangement of 5 rectangles is a non-GP, since the rectangles cannot be separated by guillotine cuts - the first cut must cross at least one rectangle:

[image]

Obviously, if we add rectangles to a non-GP, it remains non-GP, so it is easy to construct non-GPs of any cardinality.

Define a *minimal non-GP* as a non-GP of which every subset is a GP. The above pattern is not minimal, since it has a subset of 4 rectangles (the four outer recangles) that is not a GP. This subset, in turn, is a minimal non-GP, since every subset of it contains 3 rectangles that can be separated by guillotine cuts.

QUESTION: What is the largest number of rectangles in a minimal non-GP?

Comment: Based on the examples, a pattern does not have to fill a rectangle; some area within the bounding rectangle can be omitted from the pattern. Does a pattern have to be connected? If a pattern is not connected, can rectangles prevent cuts in parts of the pattern they are not connected to, or are the guillotine cuts restricted only by rectangles that are in the same connected part of the pattern? (That is, do we assume disconnected pieces can be moved away freely?)

Comment: @DavidK in the problem I had in mind, the pattern can be arbitrary (not necessarily connected), but the rectangles are fixed (cannot be moved). However, the special case where the pattern is connected is also interesting.